# Why is my time function displaying so many numbers after the period?

Tags: python

I have this code in Python:

```
W = 100
timeDP = []
timeR = []
N = 50
for n in range(10, N+1, 5):
    wt = []
    val = []
    for i in range(n):
        wt.append(random.randint(0, 100))
        val.append(random.randint(0, 100))
    start = time.time()
    t1 = time.time() - start
    timeR.append(t1)
    start = time.time()
    t2 = time.time() - start
    timeDP.append(t2)

    print("n =", n, "W =", W, "Rec Time: ", t1, "DP Time: ", t2, "Rec Max: ", knapSack(W, wt, val, n), "DP Max: ", knapSackDP(W, wt, val, n))
```

and it gives me this:

```
n = 10 W = 100 Rec Time:  1.1920928955078125e-06 DP Time:  2.384185791015625e-07 Rec Max:  249 DP Max:  249
n = 15 W = 100 Rec Time:  4.76837158203125e-07 DP Time:  0.0 Rec Max:  235 DP Max:  235
n = 20 W = 100 Rec Time:  7.152557373046875e-07 DP Time:  0.0 Rec Max:  424 DP Max:  424
n = 25 W = 100 Rec Time:  2.384185791015625e-07 DP Time:  2.384185791015625e-07 Rec Max:  292 DP Max:  292
n = 30 W = 100 Rec Time:  4.76837158203125e-07 DP Time:  2.384185791015625e-07 Rec Max:  480 DP Max:  480
n = 35 W = 100 Rec Time:  2.384185791015625e-07 DP Time:  2.384185791015625e-07 Rec Max:  474 DP Max:  474
n = 40 W = 100 Rec Time:  4.76837158203125e-07 DP Time:  0.0 Rec Max:  469 DP Max:  469
n = 45 W = 100 Rec Time:  4.76837158203125e-07 DP Time:  0.0 Rec Max:  721 DP Max:  721
n = 50 W = 100 Rec Time:  7.152557373046875e-07 DP Time:  2.384185791015625e-07 Rec Max:  687 DP Max:  687
```

Why does my Rec time and DP time have so many numbers? I initially expected them to atleast have 3-4 digits after the period. Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Why did you expect them to have 3-4 digits after the period?

Comment: It was mainly just judging from a sample thing I was looking at and it didn't produce the result that I came up with even though the code for the time function is practically the same as the example I was following.

Answer (score 0):

Use number formatting in you print line.

```
print("n = %i ,W = %i ,Rec Time: %.4e ,DP Time: %.4e" % (n, W, t1, t2))
```

**Output:**

```
n = 10 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 4.7684e-07 ,DP Time: 0.0000e+00
n = 15 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 0.0000e+00 ,DP Time: 2.3842e-07
n = 20 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 0.0000e+00 ,DP Time: 0.0000e+00
n = 25 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 2.3842e-07 ,DP Time: 2.3842e-07
n = 30 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 0.0000e+00 ,DP Time: 0.0000e+00
n = 35 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 0.0000e+00 ,DP Time: 2.3842e-07
n = 40 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 2.3842e-07 ,DP Time: 2.3842e-07
n = 45 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 0.0000e+00 ,DP Time: 0.0000e+00
n = 50 ,W = 100 ,Rec Time: 0.0000e+00 ,DP Time: 0.0000e+00
```

Comment: This worked for me although I suppose I have another issue. Do you know why the times are trailing with the "e-07" and "e+00"?

Comment: @ZackBrowning don't know what you try to measure with time. In you case you measure only time of `time.time()` invocation

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
timeR.append(round(t1, 8))
```

and

```
timeDP.append(round(t2, 8))
```

Instead of

```
timeR.append(t1)
```

And

```
timeDP.append(t2)
```